# Does the definition of the Weierstrass $\sigma$ function contain an extraneous term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

The Weierstrass $\sigma$ function of the lattice $\Lambda$ is defined by
$$\sigma (z;\Lambda)=z\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda;\,\lambda\ne 0}\left(1-\frac{z}{\lambda}\right)\exp\left(\frac{z}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{\lambda}\right)^2\right).$$
Is the factor $\exp\left(\frac{z}{\lambda}\right)$ extraneous? I.e. is this equivalent to
$$\sigma (z;\Lambda)=z\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda;\,\lambda\ne 0}\left(1-\frac{z}{\lambda}\right)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{\lambda}\right)^2\right)?$$

For every lattice point $\lambda$ there is a lattice point $-\lambda$ on the same lattice and they cancel each other:
$$\exp\left(\frac{z}{\lambda}\right)\exp\left(\frac{z}{-\lambda}\right)=1$$

Is that reasoning correct? If not, where is the error?

Comment: That's true, but $\sum_{\lambda}1/\lambda$ is **conditionally convergent**. This conditionality is avoided by using $\exp(z/\lambda)=1+{\cal O}(z/\lambda)$s on every term to offset the $(1-z/\lambda)$s so convergence is no longer conditional.

Comment: @elemelons So the convergence of the product without $\exp(z/\lambda)$ depends on the order of multiplication – what is a "correct" order? Should the products be arranged according to increasing absolute value of $\lambda$?

Comment: By "correct order" I mean one which guarantees convergence.

Comment: Specifically, convergence to $\sigma(z)$. I don't remember if you order factors by $|\lambda|$ or by $|\lambda-z|$, or if both orderings work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that for every $\lambda\in\Lambda$ there is a corresponding $-\lambda\in\Lambda$. Thus, if $\sum 1/\lambda$ converged, it would converge to $0$. But, it only converges conditionally. To think about the convergence of products, we typically take logarithms and think about the convergence of series. In this case, $\ln(1-z/\lambda)=(-1+o(1))z/\lambda$. Compare to the 1D version: the harmonic series + its negative. Of course, any of the "most obvious" ways to sum the series would do so in a symmetric manner, such as ordering terms according to magnitude, and thus yield $0$, but for bookkeeping purposes it's generally a good idea to stick to absolutely convergent things. IIRC, this isn't strictly necessary (I think some sources on Weierstrass elliptic functions live with conditional convergence), but it's a common and good idea which the source you're reading is using.

The culprit is that $(1-z/\lambda)\to1$ too slowly. To mitigate $(1-z/\lambda)$'s slow convergence, we need "offset factors" whose partial products mirror that of the original factors, i.e. converge to $1$ "just as slowly" in a fashion which "mirrors" that of $(1-z/\lambda)$ (e.g. the offset factor is "above" $1$ when the other is "below"). It is easiest to see the necessary cancellation by using $\ln$s again: the offset factors' logarithm must grow as $(+1+o(1))z/\lambda$, which means $\exp(z/\lambda)$ is the perfect choice for an offset factor.

This kind of reasoning is behind the general form of all [Weierstrass factorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem). Note the elementary factors $E_n(z)=(1-z)\exp(\Sigma^n_{k=1}z^k/k)$, when we take the logarithm, are $\ln(1-z)$ plus the $n$th partial sum of the Newton-Mercator series for $-\ln(1-z)$.